# question how to deal with KeyError: 0 or KeyError: 1 etc

Tags: python, pandas, quandl

I am new in python and this data science world and I am trying to play with different datasets.

In this case I am using the housing price index from quandl but unfortunately I get stuck when when I need to take the abbreviations names from the wiki page always getting the same Error KeyError.

```
import quandl
import pandas as pd
#pull every single housing price index from quandl

#quandl api key
api_key = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'

#get stuff from quandl
df = quandl.get('FMAC/HPI_AK',authtoken = api_key) #alaska \
##print(df.head())

#get 50 states using pandas read html from wikipedia
fifty_states = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org       /wiki/List_of_states_and_territories_of_the_United_States')
##print(fifty_states[0][1]) #first data frame is index 0, #looking for     column 1,#from element 1 on

#get quandl frannymac query names for each 50 state
for abbv in fifty_states[0][1][2:]:
#print('FMAC/HPI_'+str(abbv))
```

So the problem I got in the following step:

```
#get 50 states using pandas read html from wikipedia
fifty_states = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org       /wiki/List_of_states_and_territories_of_the_United_States')
##print(fifty_states[0][1]) #first data frame is index 0, #looking for     column 1,#from element 1 on
```

I have tried different ways to get just the abbreviation but does not work

```
for abbv in fifty_states[0][1][2:]:
#print('FMAC/HPI_'+str(abbv)) 

for abbv in fifty_states[0][1][1:]:
#print('FMAC/HPI_'+str(abbv))
```

always Keyerror: 0

I just need this step to work, and to have the following output:

```
FMAC/HPI_AL,
FMAC/HPI_AK,
FMAC/HPI_AZ,
FMAC/HPI_AR,
FMAC/HPI_CA,
FMAC/HPI_CO,
FMAC/HPI_CT,
FMAC/HPI_DE,
FMAC/HPI_FL,
FMAC/HPI_GA,
FMAC/HPI_HI,
FMAC/HPI_ID,
FMAC/HPI_IL,
FMAC/HPI_IN,
FMAC/HPI_IA,
FMAC/HPI_KS,
FMAC/HPI_KY,
FMAC/HPI_LA,
FMAC/HPI_ME
```

for the 50 states from US and then proceed to make a data analysis from this data.

Can anybody tell me what am I doing wrong ? cheers

Comment: A `KeyError` means that something is not in the dictionary. So you need to inspect the data, and look what keys are available.

Comment: Could you post type(fifty_states) and print(fifty_states) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `fifty_states` is a **list** of DataFrames, filled with
content of tables from the source page.

The first of them (at index *0* in *fifty_states*) is the table of US states.

If you don't know column names in a DataFrame (e.g. *df*),
to get column 1 from it (numeration form *0*), run:

```
df.iloc[:, 1]
```

So, since we want this column from *fifty_states[0]*, run:

```
fifty_states[0].iloc[:, 1]
```

Your code failed because you attempted to apply *[1]* to this DataFrame,
but this DataFrame has no column named *1*.

Note that e.g. `fifty_states[0][('Cities', 'Capital')]` gives proper result,
because:

- this DataFrame has a MultiIndex on columns,
- one of columns has *Cities* at the first MultiIndex level
  and *Capital* at the second level.

And getting back to your code, run:

```
for abbv in fifty_states[0].iloc[:, 1]:
    print('FMAC/HPI_' + str(abbv))
```

Note that *[2:]* is not needed. You probably wanted to skip 2 initial rows
of the *<table>* HTML tag, containing column names,
but in *Pandas* they are actually kept in the MultiIndex on columns,
so to get all values, you don't need to skip anything.

If you want these strings as a **list**, for future use, the code can be:

```
your_list = ('FMAC/HPI_' + fifty_states[0].iloc[:, 1]).tolist()
```

Comment: wow amazing answer, pretty clear and I can see better as well what I was doing wrong! thank you very  much!